# listbox item data template binding

Tags: wpf, binding, treeview, datatemplate

I have following list box and its item.

```
<ListBox Name="listBox" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding MyListItems}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="dt">
                    <controls:MyTreeControl x:Name="myTree"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

```
public class MyListItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
    }
```

The MyListItems is collection of type MyListItem and MyTreeControl is a user control which has ID as a dependency property.

Now, I want to assign each MyListItem's ID property to MyTreeControl's ID property while it is loaded.

```
<controls:MyTreeControl x:Name="myTree" ID={<I want to bind to MyListItem.ID>}/>
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each item bound to the listBox is of type `MyListItem` It should be simply

```
<controls:MyTreeControl 
                     x:Name="myTree" 
                     ID="{Binding ID}" />
```